# Php REST webservice: are those url are logical or physical?

Tags: php, rest, webservice-client

Hi I'm trying to build the server side of an application using REST archtecture with PHP. later I will make a client for android to consume those services.

I already know what is a RESTful application.

but still got something confuse:

<del>if I want to get retrieve information of a user, the url I should access is www.domain.com/user/123 according to REST. but that means for every user in DB I should make a .php?? that sounds illogical. or there are something like java which use logical url, or just rewrite the url to something like  www.domain.com/getusr.php?id=123 ??</del>

fixed: is url rewrite the correct way to interpret request url from clients for a webservice in php?
for example: if someone request www.domain.com/user/123, I should rewrite to www.domain.com/getusr.php?id=123

or maybe php is not for webservice?

thanks

Comment: How links are rewritten depends on the webserver you use. Tell us which one you use and someone will likely point you to the documentation for rewriting URLs in your webserver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite the url to `www.domain.com/getusr.php?id=123` , that way you need only 1 php file , all requests in form of `www.domain.com/user/123` would go to a single getusr.php file . You can achive this using apache mod_rewrite ( there are tons of examples around so i whont post another one ) .

---

Edit

Check [this link](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html) , that contains a few good examples .

Or you can use this code bellow ( place it inside a ".htaccess" file at the root of you're web directory , where getusr.php should be placed allso )

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^user/([0-9]+)$ getusr.php?id=$1
```

Comment: @poelinca, but you could post a link to one of those examples, it would improve your answer and help those that don't know what "search" is about. :-)

Comment: @andre matos: people who don't know what search is all about shoulnd't be doing any kind of development in the first place becouse they are lazy . people who don't know what search is all about whont get to this page ever so they whont see my updated answer . i am here to help not to be "yet another google search bot".

Comment: @andre matos There's no point in examples unless you make a wild (or educated) guess on the webserver that is being used.

Comment: @Oswald: most webservers today support apache mod_rewrite .

Comment: @poelinca, I agree but I was referring to SO search; People who use Google Search or other search engine for that matter and land here will have a link that completes your answer; @Oswald, my guess is Apache. Yes, I might be wrong but it's not my fault that info is missing... :-)

Comment: @andre matos, I think you are confused, I know how to search, but real my question actually is: is url rewrite the best way or correct way to write webservice in php? sorry for causing confusion :( my bad I will make it clear

Comment: @Kossel, That search argument wasn't because of you specifically, neither any of my comments were relevant to solve your problem (hence being comments), for that I'm sorry! :-)

Comment: @Kossel: not shure if it's needed in you're case , since you're building an android app ( don't know much about it but anyway ) , i gues the user whont see the actual url you're app requests anyway so you can have it with or without mod_rewrite . one thing is clear tough you need to have only 1 php file and pass the user id as a parameter , since the user doesn't sees it you can pass it using get , custom permalinks using mod_rewrite , post , session ...

Comment: @poelinca the last comment actually helped me! :O why I should worry about rewrite url or not, user can't even see the url duh :( sorry but the rewrite information is still useful for me! thanks

Answer (score 0):

I like the way Drupal does it. Drupal uses a `q` parameter for all of its routes:

http://myserver/drupal/?q=node/234

Which, if mod_rewrite is enabled, becomes

http://myserver/drupal/node/234

This way, you just have to parse the contents of `$_GET['q']`.

It's cleaner than having a bunch of separate rewrite rules for every one of your routes.